# Как получить изображение с вебкамеры в Rust

Tags: linux, rust, web-camera

Совсем недавно начал изучать Rust, но уже необходимо выполнить задачу - сделать программу, при запуске которой веб-камера на ноуте делает фото и хотя бы просто сохраняет его куда-либо. Долго искал в интернете, на rust материалов по проблеме не нашел. Какие вообще для этого существуют библиотеки? И с чего хотя бы начинать копать? Система - ubuntu. Буду благодарен за любые сведения по этой теме.)

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Ну так, вначале выкидываете новомодные языки, берете старый добрый с или с++, библиотеку ffmpeg/vlc и все получится.

Comment: А можно просто найти пример  https://habr.com/ru/post/467537/

Comment: Так если бы нужно было на с/с++ я бы не задавал вопросов, а за статью спасибо что-то пропустил её

Comment: У Вас есть два основных пути - взять раст, писать, мучатся, переписать на с/с++ и радоваться. или сразу написать на с/с++. Строго рекомендую второй способ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно запустить gstreamer в подпроцесс через [Popen](https://docs.rs/subprocess/latest/subprocess/) и снять картинку со стандартного вывода.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -q v4l2src num-buffers=1 ! image/jpeg,framerate=5/1,width=1280,height=960 ! jpegparse ! fdsink
```

или если в камере нет MJPG

```
gst-launch-1.0 -q v4l2src num-buffers=1 ! jpegenc ! image/jpeg,framerate=5/1,width=1280,height=960 ! fdsink
```

Чтоб посмотреть список поддерживаемых камерой форматов: `v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext`

Или если цель сделать это на rust, то ставьте rust-пакет [gstreamer-rs](https://gstreamer.pages.freedesktop.org/gstreamer-rs/stable/latest/docs/gstreamer/). Запуск gst::init(), gst::parse_launch('v4l2src num-buffers=1 ! image/jpeg,framerate=5/1,width=1280,height=960 ! jpegparse ! appsink name=out'), на  appsink вешается колбэк в котором получите буфер с картинкой